# Arithmetic series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $\left\{a_n\right\}$ arithmetic progression, $a_1=2$, $a_{n+1}=a_n+2n$ $\left(n\:\ge \:1\right)$. $a_{50}=?$

What i did:
$$a_n+d=a_n+2n$$
$$d=2n$$
$$a_{50}=2+d\left(n-1\right)$$
$$a_{50}=2+2\left(n^2-n\right)$$
$$a_{50}=2+2\cdot 2450$$
$$a_{50}=4902$$

But this is wrong. Answers:

$$A=2452,\:B=2450,\:C=2552,\:D=2500$$

Comment: This is not an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summing up the expressions $a_{n+1} = a_n + 2n$ for $n = 1, \dots, k$ one easily gets that 
$$
a_{k+1} = a_1 + \sum_{i=1}^k 2i = 2 + k(k+1)
$$

Hence, $a_{50} = 2 + 2450 = 2452$ and the correct answer is A.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}a_1&=2\\a_{n+1}&=a_n+2n\\&=a_{n-1}+2[n+(n-1)]\\&=a_{n-2}+2[n+(n-1)+(n-2)]\\
&= \ldots\\
&=a_1+2[n+(n-1)+\ldots +1]\end{align}

Hence \begin{align}a_{50}&=a_1+2(49+\ldots + 1)\\&=2+2\cdot \frac{49(50)}{2}\\&=2+49(50)\\&=2+(50-1)(50)\\&=2+2500-50\\&=2452 \end{align}

Remark:

This is not an AP, if it is an AP, the difference between consecutive terms is a constant.

Comment: I didn't understand second part please help

Comment: I just let n=49

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, note: $a_{n+1}-a_n=2n$. So:
$$\begin{align} a_2-a_1&=2\cdot 1\\
a_3-a_2&=2\cdot 2\\
a_4-a_3&=2\cdot 3\\
&\vdots \\
a_{50}-a_{49}&=2\cdot 49 \end{align}$$
Summing all (midterms telescope):
$$a_{50}-a_1=2(1+2+3+\cdots +49)  \Rightarrow \\
a_{50}=a_1+2\cdot \frac{1+49}{2}\cdot 49=2+2450=2452.$$